# R Shiny App with Tabset and Equations in Rmarkdown

Tags: html, r, shiny, r-markdown

How can you output tabsets and equations together within an rmarkdown file, render and include within a Shiny app (without rendering to HTML).

app.R

```
library(shiny)
library(knitr)

# Render beforehand
knit("example.Rmd")

ui <- fluidPage(

  uiOutput("rmarkdown")
  
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$rmarkdown <- renderUI({
    
    renderUI(withMathJax(includeMarkdown("example.md")))
    
  })
  
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

example.Rmd

```
---
title: "example"
output: html_document
date: '2022-08-05'
---

## Test 1 {.tabset}

A B C D

### TAB 1

$$
E(X)
$$
### TAB 2

$$
E(Y)
$$
```

NOTE: If I render to `html` and use `renderUI(includeHTML(app_sys("app/www/transistor_definitions.html")))`, equations and tabs are working but it breaks the UI of an app with `tabsetPanel` in app.R. Therefore I would prefer not to use this.

Comment: Are you familiar with `runtime: shiny` in your YAML? This will render your Rmarkdown with Shiny enabled, but only on your local machine, or on an external shiny server. Which would allow you to run shiny inside Rmarkdown

Comment: @Daniel_j_iii Yes, but I believe `runtime: shiny` use case is for Shiny in Rmarkdown. I would like to use Rmarkdown in Shiny.

Comment: A quick answer is no. Shiny does not know the syntax of `flexdashboard`. You would need to write custom parsers to render Rmarkdown to markdown which knows how to handle `{.tabset}`. Then include the markdown in shiny. So note the function is called `includeMarkdown` not `includeRMarkdown`